# Why are my bean leaves curled with white splotches?

Tags: diagnosis, beans, green-beans

My beans received fertilizer occasionally in the spring to get them going, and now each plant has several beans growing. However, I noticed that many leaves are curled, deformed (like an old scar), or have white patches. What could be causing these issues?

I'm in southern Ontario, Canada. These are potted plants on a high balcony with plenty of direct sunlight in late afternoon (indirect at other hours).

[image][image]

Comment: Hey toast, please send pictures of the entire plant, tell us more about the environment it resides in and your watering practices? How do you decide when the plant needs water?  Are these plants starts from the store or did you start these plants?  If I have beans (out of doors) that look like this I am not worried.  Plants in pots are a bit more vulnerable.  Did you use potting soil or did you use garden soil?  What kind of drainage do you have?  Are there any flowers yet?  What is the composition of your fertilizer (NPK)? And are these plants, when they flower available to pollinators?